# What is the appearance of humans in Jannah (Paradise)?

Tags: source-identification, jannah

I heard in a bayan that the age of men in jannah will be 33 and women will be 18 and their height will be nearly 60 feet.

What wil be the appearance of people in paradise?

Please, post some references from hadith, Quran or from tafsir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When we enter Jannah, we will resemble our Father Adam, our length will be 60 arms/cubits.

> أَخْلاَقُهُمْ عَلَى خُلُقِ رَجُلٍ وَاحِدٍ عَلَى صُورَةِ
> أَبِيهِمْ آدَمَ سِتُّونَ ذِرَاعًا فِي السَّمَاءِ
>
> They will resemble their father Adam, 60 arms/cubits in the air

[Saheeh Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2834c)

As for their ages I do not know.  As for women in jannah, they would form the minority, [Source](http://sunnah.com/urn/266000).

Comment: I also found it fascinating that women will be a minority.. What's the reason?

Comment: @AshwinSingh Gossiping

Answer (score 1):

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: "*The people of Paradise shall enter* [it] *without body hair, beardless, with Kuhl on their eyes, 30 years of age or 33 years.*" At-Tirmidhi ([2545](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2545)) Graded Sahih by Shaykh Albani in Sahih al-Jam'i ([7928](https://shamela.ws/book/10757/1246)) and At-Tirmidhi in ([2539](https://al-maktaba.org/book/782/2539)), which Shaykh Albani graded Hasan "... *their youth does not come to an end, and their clothes do not wear out*"